# MPAndroidChart: LineChart fill does not stop at XAxis

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). When I use the LineChart setDrawFilled() method to fill in the space between the line and the x-axis, and manually adjust the range to be bigger than the default, the filled in portion will go past the x-axis as seen in this screenshot:[image]

The blue fill should stop at the green dotted line, which is over the x-axis, however it extends over it and into positive y-values.

*Upon further investigation, I found only seems to happen when the green line is set to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use the `FillFormatter` interface provided by the library: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/utils/FillFormatter.java

What this class allows you to do is creating your own logic on where the "filling-line" should end.

Simply implement the `FillFormatter` class in your custom formatter class and return the value you want the fill-line to end at.

Example:

```
class MyCustomFillFormatter implements FillFormatter {

    // return the fill position
    public float getFillLinePosition(LineDataSet dataSet, LineData data, float chartMaxY, float chartMinY) {
        return 0f;
    }
}
```

Inside the `getFillLinePosition(...)` method you can of course develop your own logic on where the position of the line should be, depending on various influence factors.

After creating your formatter, set it to the `LineChart`:

```
lineChart.setFillFormatter(new MyCustomFillFormatter());
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a much better solution - thanks! Slightly unrelated question - is there anyway to customize the fill color separately above and below the x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just figured out an easy workaroun. The problem seems to lie with the limit line overlapping the x-axis - so all you have to do is prevent that 0 y-value from happening.

What I had before was:

```
LimitLine line= new LimitLine((float) foo);
```

To prevent this from happening I changed it to something like this:

```
if(foo == 0)
    foo = 0.00000001f;
LimitLine line= new LimitLine((float) foo);
```

It's not pretty, but in my case it does the job and the display looks fine. The default value formatter for the limit line rounds this value to 0 anyway, so it *should* be all good.

Fixed result:
[image]